# Windows Server 2008 on VPC (Host: Win 7)?

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpc

Is it possible to test Windows 2008 server via VPC when my host of a Windows 7 machine? I don't see anywhere where it says this is possible? The only VPC images (Windows 2008 R2) that I download from Microsoft state that the host machine must be Windows 2008. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Guess I got my answer here - http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/virtualization/q-does-windows-virtual-pc-in-windows-7-support-64-bit-guest-oss-.aspx

Virtual PC in Windows 7 does not support 64-bit guest OSs which is what Windows 2008 Server is :(

Comment: Seems we can use VirtualBox for this: http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes. I'm going to give it a try.